# Add a class to body when component is clicked?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component in vue, I wish to toggle a class on the body on click.

How can I do this? Would I just have to use JS to target the body and add a class?

Or is there more of a vue way?

For context I need to add a no scroll class to the body to prevent scrolling for an overlay menu.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have your vue instance mounted to the some div that is child of body and you don't have direct access to body element.Maybe this could help you https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that reactive binding to the body is generally frowned upon. See this [forum response by Vue team member](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-make-the-body-element-reactive/759) and [the article he links to](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#.7yrscp4y5). This makes me think there is not a "vue way" to change the body's class when a component is clicked.

So I think, like you say, targeting the body with JS is the best option.

Comment: As opposed to linking to an answer on an external site could you add a solution to your answer with some sample code?

Answer (score 33):

I think I found an elegant “vue way” by using a watcher. By setting a data attribute i.e active and toggle this on click. You can add a watcher to check if it's true or false based on this add a class or some styling to the body.

I needed this for disabling the scroll on the body when a side panel was open. I use a prop instead of data but this shouldn't matter.

```
watch: {
  // whenever active changes, this function will run
  active: function () {
    document.body.style.overflow = this.active ? 'hidden' : ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Life saving answer :)

Comment: where does `watch` needs to be? in a component?

Comment: Exactly, `watch` should be added to a component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps:

In `<template>`

```
<button @click="toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'noScroll')">Add Class</button>
<button @click="toggleBodyClass('removeClass', 'noScroll')">Remove Class</button>
```

In `<script>`

```
methods: {
  toggleBodyClass(addRemoveClass, className) {
    const el = document.body;

    if (addRemoveClass === 'addClass') {
      el.classList.add(className);
    } else {
      el.classList.remove(className);
    }
  },
},

// Just in case you like to do it when page or component is mounted or destroyed.
mounted() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'yourClassName');
},
destroyed() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('removeClass', 'yourClassName');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you will find this helpful:

- [vue-body-class NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-body-class)
- [vue-body-class GitHub](https://github.com/nikolaynesov/vue-body-class)

It allows to control your page body classes with vue-router. 
Wrote this when faced the similar issue.

Comment: How do you use your script? Could you make the instructions more clear? I am not able to let it work:(((

Answer (score 1):

i use a similar approach within a method (I call the setBodyClass() function from elsewhere as well, which is why it's wrapped in its own function:

```
methods: {
  toggleMenu() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu
    this.setBodyClass()
  },
  setBodyClass() {
    var body = document.body
    body.classList.toggle('open')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
setActive() {
  this.active = !this.active;
  let sitebody = document.body;
  this.active ? sitebody.classList.add("menu-in") : sitebody.classList.remove("menu-in");
}
```