# Changing body styles in vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-loader

I'm using [Vue router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) with two pages:

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./components/HomeView.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/intro',
        component: require('./components/IntroView.vue')
    }
]
```

This works fine, except that each of my components has different body styling:

**HomeView.vue:**

```
<template>
    <p>This is the home page!</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style>
    body {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

**IntroView.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style>
    body {
        background: pink;
    }
</style>
```

My goal is to have these two pages have different background styles (eventually with a transition between them). But at the moment when I go to the `home` route (with the `red` background), then click the `intro` route, the background colour stays `red` (I want it to change to `pink`).

Edit: 
**index.html:**

```
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-link to="/" exact>Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/intro">Introduction</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: You could use the $router object in order to add a class to your body and style it in a global sheet ?

Comment: all the styles will be available globally. so you solution is the one above

Comment: Edited my question to include my `index.html`. I can't see how I could add a class to `body` when it's outside of the app.

Comment: I tested your code and this is working fine...You have no errors ? Is the pink background applied but maybe override by red ? (this has no reason to happens tho)

Comment: Evan You suggestion in order to change body class :

`The easy way is just setting document.body.className in a global beforeEach hook.`

This solution is two years old but can still be used I guess

From : https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/656/dynamic-body-class-with-vue-router

Comment: @Mteuahasan It works until you click back to the first page. E.g. go to home page (red bg), click intro page (it changes to pink), go back to home page (it stays pink, should change back to red).

Comment: I think the `/intro` style is still there and erase the `/` style. Could you confirm ? If so, you should use the body class way (moreover it will be easier to manage, especially if you want to use transitions)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I got it working with the [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) `beforeCreate` and a global stylesheet. In `global.css`:

```
body.home {
    background: red;
}
body.intro {
    background: pink;
}
```

In the `<script>` section of `HomeView.vue`:

```
export default {
    beforeCreate: function() {
        document.body.className = 'home';
    }
}
```

And similar in `IntroView.vue`.

Comment: once added class to body, may be in another view this needs to be removed, should we use `destroyed` lifecycle hook?

Comment: you save my time!

Comment: better use nextTick

Answer (score 8):

```
watch: {
  $route: {
    handler (to, from) {
      const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      if (from !== undefined) {
        body.classList.remove('page--' + from.name.toLowerCase());
      }
      body.classList.add('page--' + to.name.toLowerCase());
    },
    immediate: true,
  }
},
```

Another fairly simple solution, add it to your base App.vue file. The to.name can be replaced with to.meta.class or similar for something more specific. This is a nice do it once and it works forever type solution though.

Comment: This is a great solution, and seems to append the class name faster than the accepted solution. The only downside is it only loads the class name when actually navigating via routes, i.e. not on initial page load (so if you refresh a single page or directly access a certain page, the class name is not appended.) Not sure if there's a way to modify it to account for this issue aside from combining it w/ the approach detailed in the selected answer?

Comment: Added the immediate flag to the watcher, but in that case there will be no 'from' route defined, so removal of the class can be skipped.

Comment: Nice (better) answer.  By the way, you can use [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) to get the body element.  It's been available forever (since IE4/1997).

Answer (score 4):

If the class is view specific, may be this will help

```
methods: {
  toggleBodyClass(addRemoveClass, className) {
    const el = document.body;

    if (addRemoveClass === 'addClass') {
      el.classList.add(className);
    } else {
      el.classList.remove(className);
    }
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'mb-0');
},
destroyed() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('removeClass', 'mb-0');
},
```

Move the `methods` section to a mixin and then the code can be DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use this

- [vue-body-class NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-body-class)
- [vue-body-class GitHub](https://github.com/nikolaynesov/vue-body-class)

It allows to control your page body classes with vue-router. 
Wrote this when faced the similar issue.
It also refers to [Add a class to body when component is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906996/add-a-class-to-body-when-component-is-clicked/47097681#47097681)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into an issue when I wanted to modify the styles of the `html` and `body` tags along with the `#app` container on specific routes and what I found out is that for various reasons, this can be quite complicated.

After reading through:

- @Saurabh's answer on another relative question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336509/2110294
- @Mteuahasan's comment above regarding Evan You's suggestion
- @GluePear's / OP's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44544595/2110294
- Sass style inclusion headaches: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/110#issuecomment-167376086

In your **App.vue** (could be considered as the centralised state):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'my-app',
    methods: {
      handleStyles () {
        // Red style to the body tag for the home page
        if (['/'].includes(this.$route.path)) document.body.className = 'bg-red'
        // Pink style to the body tag for all other pages
        else if (document.body.classList.contains('bg-red')) document.body.className = 'bg-pink'
      }
    },
    // Handle styles when the app is initially loaded
    mounted () {
      this.handleStyles()
    },
    // Handle styles when the route changes
    watch: {
      '$route' () {
        this.handleStyles()
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .bg-red {
    background: red;
  }
  .bg-pink {
    background: pink;
  }
</style>
```

So for the route `/` you get the red style and for all other routes the pink style is applied.

The `handleStyles` logic could have been dealt with by the `beforeCreated` hook however in my case, this would only affect the `html` and `body` styles but the `#app` element where the router view is rendered into would only available when the dom has been mounted so I think that it is a slightly more extensible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Top answer is right, but need some optimization.
Because that answer doesn't work when one **refreshes** that page. Reason is that dom is not loaded done when set the style you want.
So, better solution is this:

```
beforeCreate() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#f2f2f2'
  })
},
beforeDestroy() {
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = ''
},
```

By wrapping style setting handler in `this.$nextTick`, the style will be set when dom is loaded. So you can get correct styles when refresh page

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it directly in the router file using the `afterEach` hook:

```
mainRouter.afterEach((to) => {
    if (["dialogs", "snippets"].includes(to.name)) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F7F7F7";
        // or document.body.classList.add(className);
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        // or document.body.classList.remove(className);
    }
});
```

[`afterEach` hook documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks)

`to` is a route object which contains the route name (if named), path, etc.  [Documentation for all the props](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties)

Answer (score -2):

You can use scoped attribute in the style element. Then the style will be limited only to that vue file.

**HomeView.vue:**

```
<template>
    <p>This is the home page!</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    body {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

**IntroView.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Introduction</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    body {
        background: pink;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, scoped does not apply to DOM elements outside the component, like body, html, etc