# Having a hard time changing background color in Vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to make the background color of the landing page orange, but the issue is that what I currently have makes all the pages orange.

I tried adding `scoped` to the landing page so it would style only that page, but when I do this, the entire page isn't orange anymore.

The end goal is to only affect the landing page.

I've tried HTML and Body already instead of the ' * ', those don't work in this case either.

`landingpage.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class=landing>
            <h1>Hello.</h1>
            <router-link to="/work">
                <button id="work" type="button">See my work</button>
            </router-link>
            <router-link to="/home">
                <button id="home" type="button">Go home</button>
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Landing',
};
</script>

<style scoped>
* {
    background: orange;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: green;
}
#work {
    color: green;
    border: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#work:hover {
    color: white;
}
#home{
    color: green;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#home:hover {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTML` and `body` are **outside** the application (+ [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) = SPA => the body/html not re-render when you go from `page-1` to `page-2`).

**"problem one" - SPA**

On **Single File Component** - `body`, `html` Styles applies only if the **page-refresh** (Go from `page-1` to `page-2` and click <kbd>F5</kbd> for example):

```
<!-- page_2 -->
<style>
   body{
    background: orange; /* not apply if you go from page-1 to page-2 */
   }
</style>
```

**"problem two" - "out of scoped"**

`scoped` == CSS will apply to elements of the `current component` only.
`body` **is not** a part of the `current scoped component`.

#### Hello World solution

The most basic "hello world" not dynamic idea to solve this is to use [Lifecycle-Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)- On `created` change body background by simple JS. On `destroyed` remove the background.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "orange-page",
  created: function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  },
  destroyed: function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
  },
};
</script>
```

#### "min:100vh app"

One more idea is to add "wrapper" + style `min:100vh` inside your `#app` (The #app will cover the entire body/html ***set: `body { margin: 0;}`.

**Related example:**
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/change-page-background-color-each-route

### More ideas:

[Changing body styles in vue router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541872/changing-body-styles-in-vue-router)

#### css

In general use:

```
body{
   background: orange;
}
```

Not (`*` ==> selects **all** elements):

Comment: Thanks for replying.  When I tried implementing the hello world solution I got these errors:

" Unexpected unnamed method 'created'    func-names
  18:3  error    Expected method shorthand              object-shorthand
  21:3  warning  Unexpected unnamed method 'unmounted'  func-names
  21:3  error    Expected method shorthand"


Any idea how to solve them? I did a google search but didn't yield much.

Comment: First, create a simple `console.log("hello lifecycle")` in your code. You use `vue 3` or `2`?... vue-3 example: https://learnvue.co/2020/03/how-to-use-lifecycle-hooks-in-vue3/.  [2] This is a red error (The app not render) or ES-lint error?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#lifecycle-hooks

Comment: `null` is an invalid value for `backgroundColor`. Funnily enough, it actually works (because it's invalid the browser defaults to the rest of the rules applying or to its default value, which is `transparent`). But you do cause a silent error there, by passing an invalid CSS value. In theory, the proper way to do it would be to purge the style object of the current `backgroundColor` rule.

Comment: @tao Nice catch. I thinks it could be better to set the value to white or maybe initial.

Comment: Appreciate it!! This works, and I learned how to use lifecycle hooks. Thanks to you both.  However, in my script I changed "created: function ()" to " created() " Now it works with no errors.

Comment: @mike, you probably had another minor error which you fixed without realizing when you made the switch (maybe a missing comma or semicolon !?). `created: function () { ... }` is an exact equivalent of `created() { ... }` in a `VueConstructor`. I personally prefer the second syntax, as it's shorter but, since they both produce the same outcome, I rarely advocate for any of them. Both syntaxes are valid for any `hook`, `computed` or `method` (including setter/getter functions in a `computed`).

Comment: @EzraSiton, setting the value to anything (`white`, `transparent` or `initial`) in `destroyed` would be technically wrong. Assuming `body` had a `background-color` of `red` applied by some CSS, your component sets it to `orange` in `mounted` and then to `transparent` in `destroyed`. `body` now has a different bg color than before. Your component should only un-apply any rule it applied. The cleanest way would be to add a class to `body`, styled within the component and to remove that class in `destroyed`. Otherwise you might not be able to restore body's CSS initial state in all cases.

Comment: @tao nice idea to remove/add a class - Agree (very clean).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
* {
    background: orange;
}
```

do

```
html {
    background: orange;
}
```

or

```
body {
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: I tried several different things before the ' * '.  I tried body and html and both made my entire page white.

Answer (score 0):

You could also dynamically bind the class so that it only applies on the landing page route.

so, in `App.vue` or whatever upper level component that acts as the app shell, You could do something like this:

```js
/* ==== in App.vue (or Landing Page parent Component) ==== */
<template>
  <div :class={orangeBackground: $route.path.includes('/landingPagePath')}>
     // other stuff could be here - like the router view or whatever
     <router-view> </router-view>
  </div>   
</template>
<script>
</script>
<style>
.orangeBackground {
    background: orange;
}
</style>
```

The basic idea is that the entire DOM is contained within the parent component, but we only apply the `.orangeBackground` class if the browser is on the landing page route

Answer (score 0):

With the new composition API, the code look like this:

```
setup() {
  var color = "#343E3D";
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log("mounted!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
  onUnmounted(() => {
    console.log("unmounted!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
  });
  return {};
},
```

These two Lifecycle Hooks will change the background when your component is loaded/unloaded. I had a similar problem with one page needing a different background than the rest of the website.