# How to change Vue page background from a page?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

EDIT: Now I know I have to change the `body` `background-color`, but I don't know how to do this from within this page's style based on the class of the wrapper. The class is set based on the data values.

I want the entire page color to change based on the value of the data.  For example, If `hasError` is true, I want the entire page to turn red. I tried setting the width and height of .red to 100vw and 100vh but this left white space on the top and left and just shifted everything off the page slightly. This view is placed inside a `RouterView` within App.vue. The problem with this code is that only the background color changes behind the form (see screenshot), but it needs to change the entire page.
[image]
Here is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      message: '',
      infoMessage: '',
      hasError: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      const submitResponse = await websiteDataStore.submitContactForm({
        name: this.name,
        message: this.message,
      })
      this.infoMessage = submitResponse.message
      if (submitResponse.status === DbEditStatus.error) {
        this.hasError = true
      } 
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.infoMessage = ''
        this.hasError = false
      }, 10000)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div :class="{ error: hasError, success: !hasError && infoMessage }">
    <h2 v-if="infoMessage">{{ infoMessage }}</h2>
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <BaseInput label="Your Name" type="text" v-model="name" :value="name"/>
      <BaseInput label="Enter your message here:" type="text" v-model="message" :value="message"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

```css
<style>
  .error {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .success {
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having a hard time changing background color in Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418203/having-a-hard-time-changing-background-color-in-vue-js)

Comment: @MoritzRingler That helps guide me, but doesn't answer my question. It tells me that it is the background-color of the body I have to change. However, I have to set the body background-color from within this page's style based on the class of the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can fix this by programatically setting the background color of the body element in the if statement:

```
      const currentBackgroundColor = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background
      this.infoMessage = submitResponse.message
      if (submitResponse.status === DbEditStatus.error) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'red'
        this.hasError = true
      } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'green'
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.infoMessage = '';
        this.hasError = false;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = currentBackgroundColor;
      }, 10000)
```