# How can I get body html element inside the template in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to add some styles to the body element of the whole HTML page, but it seems I can't get it from the template, there is just another body element is created inside the main HTML body. And also if I try to change it by methods like

```
var elem = document.body;
elem.style.backgroundColor = 'background-color: green;';
```

nothing happens. Is it even possible to get the elements outside the template?

I could change it in App.vue through #body, but I need to change the style only in one particular component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the outer elements because I had *scoped* in style tag. But removing it would add other problems.

[Changing body styles in vue router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541872/changing-body-styles-in-vue-router)
This method works but it is kinda tricky. I thought there is more convenient way to change styles for particular templates.